# Logstash only reads file when I make manual edits into the file

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Currently, I have a program that writes a json array into a json file. The json file is initially blank. I also have an instance of logstash running with the following config file.

```
input{
 file{
        path => "/Users/CP4/Downloads/gs-accessing-data-mysql-master/complete/example.json"
        codec => "json"
        start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0

 }
}
filter     {
    mutate   {
            gsub => [ "message","\[",""]
            gsub => [ "message","\n",""]
            gsub => [ "event","\},\{",","]
        }
    json { source => message }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "test123"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

For some reason, logstash will only read the file once I go in and make some changes manually, rather than when my program writes json to it. What could be causing this? Is the way my config file is set up wrong? Thanks.